# WCF - File transfer binding question

Tags: c#, wcf, file, binding

Im trying to create file transfer service over WCF, but i got some problems setting binding.

Im getting: Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8080/FileTransfer.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

Here is my host side configuration:

http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/7203/hostj.png

and here is the client side configuration:

http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/425/clientp.png

Sorry for images, but i was unable to paste the code here...
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you assign addresses to clients? It somehow looks like your MessageService client communicates with FileTransfer service. Because your problem is that client configured for SOAP 1.2 (WsHttpBinding) calls service configured for SOAP 1.1 (BasicHttpBinding).

Comment: my mistake. The error was obvious on client. Thanx for pointing it out. But now i have new problem. The FileTransferService has Download method that has returnType "Stream". When the method returns a fileStream i get ProtocolException: The content type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:71505aad-15db-4b0d-b04b-794dd64917e0+id=2";start-info="text/xml" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was obvious on client. Fixed.